# Use jfrog-cli to recursively download nuget package along with it's dependencies

Tags: nuget, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have the following structure in Jfrog Artifactory for NuGet repository

```
nuget-virtual-repo
                |__package1.1.0.nupkg
                |__package2.2.0.nupkg
                |__package3.3.0.nupkg
```

Now package1.1.0 have a dependency on package2.2.0 and it is mentioned in it nuget.dependency property:

`nuget.dependency package2:2.0:`

Also package2.2.0 have a dependency on package3.3.0 and it is mentioned in it's nuget.dependency property:
`nuget.dependency package3:3.0:`

Now when I try to download package1.1.0 using jfrog-cli it does not downloads the other dependent package along with it:

```
jfrog-cli.exe rt dl --apikey=<API_KEY> --url=https://<artifactory_url> --detailed-summary nuget-virtual-repo/package1.1.0.nupkg
```

Output:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "source": "https://<artifactory_url>/nuget-virtual-repo/package1.1.0.nupkg",
      "target": "package1.1.0.nupkg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using spec file also with this inside but here also it download only 1 package:

```
'files': [
                {
                    'target': 'C:\JfrogCli',
                    'pattern': 'nuget-virtual-repo/*',
                    'props': 'nuget.id=package1;nuget.version=1.0',
                    'limit': 1,
                    'sortOrder': 'desc',
                    'sortBy': ['created']
                }
         ]
```

What I want is to download the dependencies recursively i.e. it should download package2.2.0.nupkg and package3.3.0.nupkg. I check the documentation but didn't found any flag to do that. Is there anything I can change maybe in spec file to download the dependencies without mentioning them explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot replace the dependencecy management logic implemented by nuget with only the JFrog cli.

While JFrog cli can be used to authenticate on artifactory and gather metadata during resolution and uploads of artefacts you still need the nuget (or .net core)  client to interact with the nuget api exposed by the repository and get through the dependency graph of requested packages

What you can do is to use the JFrog cli with native client as documented here : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-BuildingNuGetPackages

```
jfrog rt nugetc --server-id-resolve=<artifactoryServerID> --repo-resolve=nuget-virtual-repo
```

and then

```
jfrog rt nuget install package1 -Version 1.0
```

This should install all transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question. In case we want to download the nupkg file and not extract it, is there any way I can do it using nuget?

nuget install extracts the content of nupkg file.

Comment: Hi, I do not think nuget client allows such operation. For the record when you use jfrog rt nuget command, the jfrog cli is just a wrapper for the nuget client so it cannot change native behaviours of the client. It would be nice to have a bit more context about the use case to better understand what you are trying to achieve.